# How do I find Hash type If I know INPUT an OUTPUT

Tags: encryption, types, hash, cryptography, output

I have an encrypted hash and I don't know the HASH TYPE.
I have 2 alternatives, **one of them is surely correct** *(matches INPUT with OUTPUT)*. How can I find the hashtype using them?

> **INPUT1** = 123459999
> **OUTPUT1** = eb6ae08384753f42445b7418661924c1632d36c06d1f3695e2ec90c192e7f92a

> **INPUT2** = 123-45-9999
> **OUTPUT2** = eb6ae08384753f42445b7418661924c1632d36c06d1f3695e2ec90c192e7f92a

**I would rlly appreciate If someone can find the HASH TYPE or explain how should I find it, please :)**

Comment: Since there are many different hash types, about all you can do is try different ones until you find one that matches.

Comment: Yeah, there should be a lot of different hash types. I tried with SHA2-256 and sadly It doesn't looks like It works! Anyway, thx for ur comment!

Comment: [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) create an output of a certain length. In your case it's 256 Bit. That reduces the list of potential candidates.

Comment: You can check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions to see if any of those seem plausible.  But you're best off trying to get more info or hints as to which hash function is being used from where your getting the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific way to know what hash function is used here.  A cryptographic hash function produces output indistinguishable from random, so we can't distinguish between the outputs of different secure hash functions (or we'd be able to also distinguish them from random).

However, there are some common hash functions that are in use.  Since this is a 256-bit output, you could try SHA-256, SHA-512/256, SHA-3-256, BLAKE2s, or BLAKE2b-256 and see if one of those produces the expected output.  However, it is also equally plausible that somebody produced these hashes using a 256-bit MAC, like HMAC-SHA-256, which is essentially a hash function with a key, in which case there's no way to reproduce the hash without knowing the key.